# Creating collection fields JSP Java

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I am using Spring framework, JSP pages to display and validate form.

I am from PHP world where field names like `somefield[]` is represented by array (`ArrayList` in Java). I want to grab collection of strings from input in my form.

I have defined `private List<String> waypoints;` which works perfectly, but in JSP I have to keep notation `somefield[0]`, `somefield[1]`, `somefield[2]`, etc...

**Problem:**
This make an inconvenience, causes that sequence of only two fields:  `somefield[0]`, `somefield[9]` generates in fact 10 fields.

My simply code to display existing field's values.

```
<c:forEach items="${routeAddInput.waypoints}" var="waypoint" varStatus="status">
    <input name="waypoints[${status.index}]" type="text" value="${waypoint}"  placeholder="Enter name here" />
</c:forEach>
```

**Question:**
Is it a possible to genereate fields dynamically by user (in UI), where indexes doesn't matter? If user add the field, i can simply calculate next index, but if user removes the field, in the list there is a gap.

**Question context:**
My Servlet method to validate form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String step1ValidateForm(
    @ModelAttribute("routeAddInput")
    @Valid RouteAddInput form,
    BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "route/add";
    }

    return "redirect:addDetails";
}
```

The form to validate:

```
public class RouteAddInput {
    @NotNull
    @Length(min=1)
    private String locationSource;

    @NotNull
    @Length(min=1)
    private String locationDestination;

    private List<String> waypoints;

  public RouteAddInput() {
    setLocationSource("");
    setLocationDestination("");
    waypointsCoords = new ArrayList<String>();
  }

    public String getLocationSource() {
        return locationSource;
    }

    public void setLocationSource(String locationSource) {
        this.locationSource = locationSource;
    }

    public String getLocationDestination() {
        return locationDestination;
    }

    public void setLocationDestination(String locationDestination) {
        this.locationDestination = locationDestination;
    }

    public List<String> getWaypoints() {
        return waypoints;
    }

    public void setWaypoints(List<String> waypoints) {
        this.waypoints = waypoints;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem. The key is to use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `ArrayList`.

`LinkedHashMap` preserves the values order and **allows to keep indexes as you like**. In particular integers.

So the in the form class this field will be:
private HashMap waypoints;

And there is the difference in JSP `forEach`:

```
<c:forEach items="${routeAddInput.waypoints}" var="waypoint">
  <input name="waypoints['${waypoint.key}']" type="text" value="${waypoint.value}"  placeholder="Enter name here" />
</c:forEach>
```